# What is "." in matlab search path?

Tags: matlab, path

I'm trying to set up the search path of my laptop matlab. I saw "." in my office computer matlab(set up by someone else).

What does . mean?
How can I add . also as my search path. I tried to add it but it failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods for specifying paths: *absolute* and *relative* paths.
An absolute path is e.g. `C:\some\folder` in Windows, or e.g.`/Some/folder` in Linux and Mac. As the name says, these are absolute and always the same. Relative paths however are paths specified in relation to the current working directory.

When creating relative paths, `.` is the current working directory. `..` similarly is the parent directory. This can be used to add subfolders to the path, e.g. `./subfolder` or add another directory which in located in the parent directory, e.g. `../other_directory`.

Afaik, you don't need to add the current working directory to the search path, as this is the default behavior of MATLAB.